# Parallel FFT wth FFTW in Fortran crashes

Tags: fortran, mpi, fftw

My aim is to parallelize a serial FFTW code written in Fortran, which tells us the finite strain distributions in a material. I need to only parallelize the forward Fourier transform and the backward transform to remain as it is. 
Is it possible to do that first of all? I've tried doing it but getting some segmentation faults. I can actually paste the entire code but it's 1600 lines but I'll attach where the error persists.

Assume the initialization of other trivial variables and required headers.

```
   complex ( C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX )  , dimension ( : , : , : ), pointer :: in_forward !> @var Array input in FFT
complex ( C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX ) ,  dimension ( : , : , : ), pointer :: out_forward !> @var Array output in FFT
complex ( C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX ) ,  dimension ( : , : , : ), allocatable :: in_backward !> @var Array input of FFT-1
complex ( C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX ) ,  dimension ( : , : , : ), allocatable :: out_backward !> @var Array output for FFT-1

  ALLOCATE delta(3,3,npts1,npts2,local_npts3))


  integer (kind = i4b ) :: plan_forward 
  integer (kind = i4b ) :: plan_backward
  integer :: AllocateStatus
    CALL MPI_INIT(ier)
    CALL fftw_mpi_init
    call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, IER)
    call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, IER)

 ur0=0

  open(ur0,file='elfft.in',status='old')
  read(ur0,'(a)') prosa
  read(ur0,*),npts1,npts2,npts3

npts1_c = npts1
npts2_c = npts2
npts3_c = npts3

alloc_local = fftw_mpi_local_size_3d(npts3_c, npts2_c, npts1_c, MPI_COMM_WORLD, local_npts3_c, local_j_offset_c)
local_npts3 = local_npts3_c
local_j_offset = local_j_offset_c
cdata = fftw_alloc_complex(alloc_local)

 CALL C_F_POINTER(cdata, in_forward, [npts1_c, npts2_c, local_npts3_c])


do vii=1,3
 do vjj=1,3

  in_forward(:,:,:) = CMPLX(delta(vii,vjj,:,:,:),0)


      if (imicro == 1 .and. iter  == 1 .and. vii == 1 .and. vjj == 1 ) then
        plan = fftw_mpi_plan_dft_3d(local_npts3_c,npts2_c,npts1_c, in_forward , out_forward, MPI_COMM_WORLD, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE)

        print *, 'successful plan creation for forward'  
      endif    

    call fftw_mpi_execute_dft( plan,in_forward, out_forward )
     .
     . 
    call fftw_destroy_plan(plan)
    call fftw_free(cdata)
```

After compiling and running the program, I'm getting this error.
***I still feel I've done something incomplete and want to have a better understanding. So if someone can suggest me any sample source code or reference material, it'd be great.***

```
Error in `./a.out': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer successful plan creation for forward

 successful plan creation for forward

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've tried doing it but haven't got a proper source yet. I guess I need to search more. I've edited and added the part where I've tried something. It might look sluggish. Please give me any sort of feedback.

Comment: *"Assume the initialization of other trivial variables and required headers."* Don't do this, put here a [mcve], notice the word **complete**. We should be able to compile and test the code. If it is too long, delete the irrelevant parts, but the code should remain compilable and still should have the error. What you deleted are the necessary parts, not the irrelevant ones.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow ! As `C_F_POINTER(cdata, in_forward,...)` is called, it assigns the allocated C pointer to the fortran pointer. Nevertheless, the fortran array `out_forward` does not seem to be allocated, which could trigger the reported error. See this example, where allocation functions are called twice, once for input and once for output. http://fftw.org/doc/Multi_002ddimensional-MPI-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html